# What are the module categories with finitely many modules with trivial endomorphism ring?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

If an finite-dimensional k-algebra is representation finite, there are also finitely many endotrivial (finite-dimensional) modules M, i.e. with trivial endomorphism ring Hom(M,M)=k.There are representation-infinite module categories with finitely many endotrivial modules, e.g. modules over the preprojective algebras of certain Dynkin quivers.

What are the representation-infinite module categories with finitely many endotrivial modules?

Comment: Take the category of representations of any nontrivial field extension of $k$.